# Avoid a long delay when checking for a file in a disconnected shared directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

When checking if a file exists in a shared directory

```
if exist \\10.0.0.10\disk\file echo yes
```

I experience a very long delay in case the shared directory is disconnected.

I need a faster way to perform this check.

I have tried several alternatives

```
pushd \\10.0.0.10\disk

if exist \\10.0.0.10\disk\nul

net use \\10.0.0.10\disk
...
```

but all of them fail after an unacceptable long delay

is there any faster (say less than 1 sec) way?

Or is there any net configuration parameter that can change this timeout?

**Edited for clarification** The problem is not to reconnect to a specific shared folder. The question is to recognize without having to wait long delays, if a file in a shared folder exists.

This is a bat file that collects information from many different sources, user defined, and some of them can be (and eventually very often are) files in shared folders. Some users may configure dozens of possible sources, and some of them might not be not available when the bat is run. So, those locations will be ignored. But I dont want it to impact the overall performance of the process.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to check if the server is up first using ping:

```
ping 10.0.0.10 -n 1 -w 100
```

Use `%ERRORLEVEL%` to check the result, `0` for success, `1` for failure.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you can change your location, so it's possible that there is also an ip 10.0.0.10 but it's not the correct device.

You can check first the status of the `net use` output (findstr can also be used here)

```
net use | awk '/((Not)|(Connected)).*10.0.0.10\\disk:/{print $1}'
```

If this fails, you need to check if it's possible to reconnect.

A `ping -n 1 10.0.0.10` could help, but it doesn't tell if it's the correct device.
You can check then the MAC of 10.0.0.10 against an expected value, but you should do the *dummy* ping before to get a reliable result from `arp`.

```
arp -a 10.0.0.10 | findstr "12-34-56-12-34-56"
```

and if this is successful then you can reconnect

```
net use \\10.0.0.1\disk
```

Comment: thanks, I have edited my question in clarification.  `NET USE` is not relevant, as the files in question reside in shared folders which may not be *mounted* and probably never will. A `ping` as Ashigore also suggests is a good strategy, because it will help me decide to go ahead or not with a `IF EXIST` check. Also, an `arp` check on the MAC is not possible, as the user will not be providing this information. So, I will leave something like `ping` and if no error, go ahead with `if exist`.